# Passing Struct pointers in function: expected declaration specifiers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct declared as following:

```
typedef struct data
{
        double open;
        double high;
        double low;
        double close;
} ohlcstruct;
```

How do I pass the pointer to the function `printEOD()`

I am doing something like below:

```
ohlcstruct * pohlctemp;
pohlctemp = (ohlcstruct *)(long long)GetPfData(sPFName, 1);
printEOD(args, pohlctemp);
```

I declared the function `printEOD()` as below:

```
void printEOD(void **args, ohlcstruct ** pohlctemp); //Error here
```

This is giving an error as expected declaration specifiers

Please help!

Comment: It looks like you've way over complicated this , `ohlcstruct pohlctemp;` , `printEOD(args,&pohlctemp);`  ,`void printEOD(void** args,ohlcstruct* pohlctemp);`

Comment: You need the struct (forward, at least) declaration in the same source file as the function. That is usually done by including a header with the declaration in all files which us the struct. Btw, you need to take the address of `pohlctemp` or change the function declaration to `void printEOD(void **args,ohlcstruct * pohlctemp);` (note the single star in front of `pohlctemp`).

Comment: void printEOD(void **args,ohlcstruct* pohlctemp); even this is giving the same error expected declaration specifiers
Please help with this @George

Comment: @Akshay Well there's no mvce so I can't say exactly why but, why change `args` to a pointer and `pohlctemp` to a value type? The `expected declaration specifiers ` is probably because something hasn't been forward declared, though obviously I can't say for sure.

Comment: In my compiler I have errors different as yours. Can you post here the entire code?

Answer (score 1):

With the printEOD() function declaration that you have, it expects a pointer to a pointer to an ohlcstruct and you would need to call:

```
printEOD(args, &pohlctemp);
```

A simpler printEOD() declaration would be:

```
printEOD(void **args, oblcstruct *pohlctemp);
```

which would then be called as:

```
printEOD(args, pohlctemp);
```

Comment: An even simpler one would be to pass by value :-).

Comment: `void printEOD(void **args,ohlcstruct* pohlctemp);` even this is giving the same error expected declaration specifiers

Answer (score 0):

Your signature of function `printEOD()` should be like:

```
void printEOD(void **args,ohlcstruct* pohlctemp); /* pohlctemp should be a single pointer instead of a double pointer */
```

You can simply call printEOD() like the same way:

```
printEOD(args,pohlctemp);
```

Comment: This also is giving the same error expected declaration specifiers

Comment: Please write down your complete code and mention the line number at which you are getting this error.